# Force folders to NOT save their appearance

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, templates

I've just switched to fresh Win10, and 
I found that I haven't backed up one **system tweak** I had.

That tweak is somewhat hard to describe 
(since I'm not sure what 'tweaker' I used; like, years ago), but 
the idea is that **NONE of my** *usual* **folders** (meaning *any* typical user folder; except for libraries, 'This PC' and very few others) **were saving changes to their appearance**.

For instance, if I had sorted contents of some folder, say, 'by Date'; or enlarged icons 
— these changes would've persisted only until I closed active window.

Meaning, that the next time I opened that same folder 
— it would've appeared as 'default' view (without sorting 'by Date', or any other viewing feature I might have changed; like icon sizes).

***Therefore**, all usual folders had the same icon sizes and sorting\grouping options, 

and never had saved any changes to them.*

And.. it may sound ridiculous, as this 'tweak' is one of many reasons I finally found a time to reinstall Windows; but now I'm actually missing it very-very much :(

:) Because now navigating the filesystem feels like a giant mess 
— when any time I open a folder and can't be sure what place to point my mouse to 
(due to enormous variety of layouts).

Does anyone have any idea how can I edit my registry to reinforce this 'tweak' 
— ?.. May be disable 'Bags' somehow, or something; of which I know only a bit.

Comment: What do you mean by a fresh Windows 10, and how could a fresh install have tweaks?

Comment: I mean that I switched to fresh Windows 10, and I found that I haven't backed up one system tweak I had on my old (not fresh) Windows.

Comment: If you installed a fresh Windows version, meaning not an upgrade, there should be no tweaks.

Comment: that was not in question, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works like a charm))
Too bad this instruction is quite long
(it actually takes 2 minutes to perform).

Yet, here's how I figured it on my Windows 10.

1. Create new text document.
   Rename it from `New Text Document.txt` to `foo.reg`.
   Check online "how to change file extension" if you don't see `.txt`.

Open it and save following code there:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU]
[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell]
"FolderType"="NotSpecified"
"WFlags"=dword:0
```

If you will launch `foo.reg` - it will erase appearances of all your folders (including window sizes and positions) to default via deleting 2 Registry keys (paths that start with `HKEY` as texted above).
Check online "how to back up Registry keys" in case you may need those.

But we're not launching or tweaking anything yet.

2. Create another text document (right next to `foo.reg`).
   Rename it from `New Text Document.txt` to `foo.bat`.

Open it and save following code there:

```
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe

foo.reg
start regedit.exe
start explorer.exe
```

You can launch `foo.bat` now; if you do - it will restart `explorer.exe` (because it needs to be) and will launch `foo.reg` for you in between.

Make sure that your Registry Editor is closed.
Once launched, `foo.bat` will ask your permission to make changes 2 or more times.
You will know once it's done when you'll see Registry Editor window pop up.

Do not open folders before final step!

3. In Registry Editor opened
   — navigate to (you probably can just paste this to the header):

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell`

Select `Shell` entry (like, folder) and right click it.
Select `Permissions...` from Shell's context menu.

In opened window, click `Advanced` button near bottom.
`Advanced Security Settings for Shell` window will open.

In the top, you will see 'Owner' line.
If your UserName (or at least something very similar) is placed there
— go ahead to step 5.

Otherwise - click `Change` caption in the end of 'Owner' line.

4. Small window will open.
   Just start typing your UserName in it and press `Check Names` button.
   If your UserName (or at least something very similar) is placed there
   — click 'OK'.

Back in `Advanced Security Settings for Shell`
— you will see now your UserName is placed in 'Owner' line.

5. In the bottom left corner of that same window,
   click `Disable inheritance` button.

A warning will pop up: answer it with **the second** option 'Remove all inherited permissions...'.

'Permission entries' list will now be empty.
Go ahead and click `Add` button from the same bottom left corner.

We almost done, I swear ><

`Permission Entry for Shell` window will now open.
Go with `Select principal` caption in the top there.
In familiar small window, start typing your UserName,
press `Check Names` and click 'OK'.

On the middle right side of `Permission Entry for Shell`
— click `Show advanced permissions`.

Check all boxes (starting with the first),
but **uncheck** those:

```
Query Value
Set Value
Create Subkey
Enumerate Subkeys
```

Press 'OK'.

6. Lastly! Back in `Advanced Security Settings for Shell`
   — make sure 'Replace all child object permissions...' checkbox **is checked**,
   and press 'OK'.

Press 'Yes' to the warning.

### DONE!

---

From now on, none of your folders will remember changes you're applying to them
— every single folder will **always** appear just as after you installed Windows
(except for few system ones), simply because we've banned our own system
(ourselves including) from accessing these few Registry keys.

Just one problem I haven't figured out yet:
folders won't remember changes to their sizes and positions as well
(because they're located in the same `Shell` entry); perhaps 3rd party software like `cmdow` by ritchielawrence will be the best option here.

**If you'd like to reverse it all**
— just repeat step 5 (and step 6; no need to click `Add` button this time) with `Enable inheritance`
(instead of Disable) button, and 'OK' away without any warning.

But! Why reverse it,
when **you can still customize appearances** of your folders
— via changing folder templates!

Check online "how to customize folder templates" for more info.
They will all be listed here once you done customizing:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Defaults`

Here's how to understand what's what there from my experience:

```
Usual folders:

"{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}" are General items
"{5FA96407-7E77-483C-AC93-691D05850DE8}" are Videos
"{7D49D726-3C21-4F05-99AA-FDC2C9474656}" are Documents
"{94D6DDCC-4A68-4175-A374-BD584A510B78}" are Music
"{B3690E58-E961-423B-B687-386EBFD83239}" are Pictures
"{885A186E-A440-4ADA-812B-DB871B942259}" are Downloads (Windows 10)

Libraries:

"{5f4eab9a-6833-4f61-899d-31cf46979d49}" are General items
"{631958a6-ad0f-4035-a745-28ac066dc6ed}" are Videos
"{fbb3477e-c9e4-4b3b-a2ba-d3f5d3cd46f9}" are Documents
"{3f2a72a7-99fa-4ddb-a5a8-c604edf61d6b}" are Music
"{0b2baaeb-0042-4dca-aa4d-3ee8648d03e5}" are Pictures
```

Complicated? Yes.
But settle it once! Write simple batch, and
never click all these menus again!